# Parameter passing in function

Tags: python, function, beautifulsoup, parameters

Seems like this has been addressed over the years that Python has been around, but here goes anyway:

```
def soupstrainer(tag_element,srch_str):
    ''' take a soup element
        return a list of found items
    '''
    results=[]
    ###literal search string returns results, even though two lines down,
    ### print(srch_str) returns the expected string
    souper=tag_element.find_all('a',{'data-tn-element':'companyName'}) #srch_str)
    print(srch_str)
    for r in souper:
        if r != None:
            results.append(r.get_text(r.string, strip=True))
    return results

with open('scrapesnip.html', 'r') as the_file:
    doc4 = the_file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(doc4, 'html.parser')
result = soupstrainer(soup,str("'a',{'data-tn-element':'companyName'}"))
print(result,len(result))
```

Results:

```
## zero results passing the string
/PYscripts/bravosierra4.py
'a',{'data-tn-element':'companyName'}        <=== these two strings *look* identical
[] 0

## with the identical string
## 'hard coded' into the function
/PYscripts/bravosierra4.py
'a',{'data-tn-element':'companyName'}         <=== these two strings *look identical
['Keysight Technologies', 'ECS Federal LLC', 'Corsica Technologies, LLC', 'Caribou', 'Collins Aerospace', 'Travelers', 'CyberCoders', 'HealthVerity', 'Circadence Corporation'] 9
```

Am I passing `srch_string` incorrectly?

Comment: The complete mess of bits of code and output shared above makes it very hard to say anything sensible about your problem - and I get the feeling the compiler may feel the same way. Please clarify the issue, share some code that people can run to reproduce the problem and explain what you expected and what happened instead.

Comment: You are passing two completely different things!

Comment: Fair enough, looks messy to me too! I'll try to distill: 
1. Function soupstrainer takes two params, the HTML glob tag_element and what I'm looking to strain out of the glob, i.e., search_str.

Comment: 2. @juanpa.arrivillaga, I think I'm passing only one object of type string. But I must be passing in a way the function isn't expecting, I use print(srch_str) in the line below the find_all, and it seems to be the identical string to the one that works when I paste it into the function (hard-code).

Comment: `souper=tag_element.find_all('a',{'data-tn-element':'companyName'})` isn't passing in a string! that is two different arguments, one a string, the other a dict. `"'a',{'data-tn-element':'companyName'}"` is a string. See the answer below

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how exactly you're passing `srch_string`, but this:

```
souper = tag_element.find_all('a', {'data-tn-element': 'companyName'})
```

is not the same as this:

```
srch_string = "'a', {'data-tn-element': 'companyName'}"
souper = tag_element.find_all(srch_string)
```

In the first case, you're passing a string and a dict as separate arguments.  In the second case, you're passing a single string.  Code that you put into a string variable doesn't get evaluated as code inside of other expressions (and it would be a really big problem if it did).

You could do this instead:

```
def soupstrainer(tag_element, *srch_args):
    """take a soup element and search args, return a list of found items"""
    souper = tag_element.find_all(*srch_args)
    return [r.get_text(r.string, strip=True) for r in souper if r is not None]

...
result = soupstrainer(soup, ,'a', {'data-tn-element': 'companyName'})
```

so that `soupstrainer` just takes the search arguments as separate arguments (instead of packing them into a single string) and passes them straight along to `find_all`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks as though BeautifulSoup is parsing the find_all as a natural list, so when it shows up as a string, nothing is returned. Here's the way I successfully coded the line calling the function:

```
result = soupstrainer(soup,['a',{'data-tn-element':'companyName'}])
```

and recoded the function like this:

```
def soupstrainer(tag_element,srch_str):
    ''' take a soup element 
        return a list of found items
    '''
    results=[]
    souper=tag_element.find_all(srch_str[0],srch_str[1])
```